# Getting error everytime while running my python code

Tags: python, imutils

I want to run this code, but get this error 
(I currently have 0.4.6 version of imutils package installed)

**Error:**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "object_size.py", line 42, in <module>
    cnts = imutils.grab_contours(cnts)
AttributeError: module 'imutils' has no attribute 'grab_contours'
```

Comment: can you share your code?

Comment: https://github.com/jrosebr1/imutils/issues/84 says to run `$ pip install --upgrade imutils`

Comment: That function wasn't added until Dec 3, 2018, but version 0.4.6 was released Mar 18, 2018. You need to update like @JacobIRR said.

Answer (score 3):

`grab_contours` was added in this commit on 3 December 2018:
https://github.com/jrosebr1/imutils/commit/5aae9887df3dcada5f8d8fa6af0df2122ad7aaca

Version 0.4.6 was released on 18 March 2018:
https://pypi.org/project/imutils/#history

Your version doesn't have it yet. You need version 0.5.2 (the current latest release).

Run `pip install --upgrade imutils` to upgrade it, as [JacobIRR](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4225229/jacobirr) mentioned in a comment.

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem by removing older version of imutil and installed 0.5.2 version of grab_contours from https://pypi.org/project/imutils